# random graphs without cycles

Tags: probability, reference-request, graph-theory

Recall that a closed walk (in a undirected graph) is a cycle if its vertices are pairwise distinct.

Does there exist random constructions of bipartite graphs without cycles with high probability?

Comment: You might be looking for [LERW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk) and [UST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk#The_uniform_spanning_tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a graph has no cycles then it is clearly bipartite. Moreover a graph without 
cycles is a forest. So what you really want is generate trees/forests?

If you're looking to generate random labeled forests/trees then this can be done efficiently using Prüfer sequences. Every such sequence chosen at random gives you a specific labeled tree.

Random non labeled forest are a bit harder to generate.